# Mercurial and netbeans is there a way to return a file to a specific date?

Tags: java, netbeans, mercurial

I have a project with severial files. I want to return 3 of those files to a specific date in time. I used this.

[image]

But this so misleading. When I supposedly would recover all the code of 2018. But it doesn't it has things of 2019, 2020.

[image]

To solve the issue I have to have an exact copy of the time.

Comment: I don't think this is a `git` question

Comment: ... but since it is tagged, with git you should use `git restore --worktree --source=<some-commit-id-or-branch> -- <the-files-you-want>`. That will get you the files like that in the working tree, won't mess up with the index. You could also do `git checkout <some-commit-id-or-branch> -- <the-files-you-want>` but using `restore` is preferred these days.

Comment: Are you using git or mercurial? Don't just thow in the tags, they do have a meaning.